# Pinit button with unique URL for each image (category page with images linking to post pages)

Tags: html, pinterest

I am  trying to give users the ability to pin posts from category pages:

Functionality: Hover over a post image and the pin button shows up which pins that specific post URL with title pulled from post.

The only way they should be able to pin is clicking the button, clicking anywhere on the image should take the user to the post page itself.

I know I can't have two HREF attributes but I'm stuck - this code is breaking the images entirely and none of the data is being pulled as specified (description, post url, etc).

```
script async defer src="//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>

<a data-pin-do="buttonPin" data-pin-hover="true" data-pin-url="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" data-pin-description="<?php the_title(); ?>" href="https://www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__('%s', 'minti'), the_title_attribute('echo=0') ); ?>" rel="bookmark">
    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
</a>
```

Thank you!

Figured out the solution in case anyone ever needs:

```
<div class="entry-image">
        <script async defer src="//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>
        <?php $feat_image = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) ); ?>
        <div class="pinbutton" style="position: absolute; top: 10px; right: 10px; display: none;"><a data-pin-do="buttonPin" data-pin-hover="true" data-pin-media="<?php echo $feat_image; ?>" data-pin-url="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" data-pin-description="<?php the_title(); ?>" href="https://www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/"></a></div>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__('%s', 'minti'), the_title_attribute('echo=0') ); ?>" rel="bookmark">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
        </a>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('.entry-image').mouseenter(function() {
            $(this).children('.pinbutton').fadeIn('fast');
        }); 
        $('.entry-image').mouseleave(function() {
            $(this).children('.pinbutton').fadeOut('fast');
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess answer is waiting for you here: [Pinterest Developers](https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/widgets/pin-it/)

Comment: Thanks but the answer is not there. You can't have an '<a' tag with two HREF attributes. But they require their '<a' tag have https://www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/ while the image actually needs to link to the post URL.

Comment: You will need HTML, CSS and JS there then, but i don't know JS as well. I recommend you to try to make <div> for each pin-it button, then show it on hover.

Comment: Good idea! This should be possible with a little css maneuvering. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution requires some js/css and (in this case) wordpress calls:

```
<div class="entry-image">
        <script async defer src="//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>
        <?php $feat_image = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) ); ?>
        <div class="pinbutton" style="position: absolute; top: 10px; right: 10px; display: none;"><a data-pin-do="buttonPin" data-pin-hover="true" data-pin-media="<?php echo $feat_image; ?>" data-pin-url="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" data-pin-description="<?php the_title(); ?>" href="https://www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/"></a></div>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__('%s', 'minti'), the_title_attribute('echo=0') ); ?>" rel="bookmark">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
        </a>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('.entry-image').mouseenter(function() {
            $(this).children('.pinbutton').fadeIn('fast');
        }); 
        $('.entry-image').mouseleave(function() {
            $(this).children('.pinbutton').fadeOut('fast');
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php } ?>
```